# .net7 Web API User Secrets not loading

Tags: .net-7.0, user-secret

I have followed the instructions as per the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=windows#register-the-user-secrets-configuration-source).

the secrets are not loading for some reason. I'm MacOS using Visual Studio

I tried adding manually using `builder.Configuration.AddUserSecrets<Program>();`

Comment: Can you share your `Program.cs` and the way you are trying to access the secrets?

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake, I had a typo. Everything is working fine. I did not have to make any changes